# Wrap all of Rails DB/ActiveRecord calls in a Transaction, so can Rollback to previous state at end

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, activerecord

I have a Rails app that needs to make changes to a DB, is there a way I can set it up so that all the DB actions are rolled-back at the end, like a Sandbox/Transaction?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it helps you out, but you can always run `rails console` in sandbox mode: `rails c -s`. This will automatically rollback all transactions once you exit the console.

You can check out the `database_cleaner` gem too.

Comment: That sounds cool, if only I could run my whole app in Sandbox mode?

Comment: Can I do `rails s -s`? i.e. start my rails app in sandbox mode? That would be cool!

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, I don't think there's something like that. The best I can think of is, if you need something like that, have something like a rake task (a seed file for example) to clear up the database, then load all your data.

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap every request in an around filter that explicitly starts a transaction and does a rollback when yield returns. Adding it to ActionController::Base should do?

Do make a backup first, btw :p

Another option could be to hit serverfault and ask for help with filesystem snapshots.

Comment: That is one way, but would be a bit of a pain wrapping all the callsm even with a nice accessor method! Not only that, but the queries might need to depend on each other, thus I cannot just rollback each one, as the next one might need the result of the previous.

Comment: I do mean web requests, as in actions, not individual db requests. Not sure how it'll integrate with any transaction control you do in your app, though. A filesystem with snapshot capabilities might be a better solution?